# Sometimes data are not loaded from sqllite in Phonegap

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I am using SQLLite in Phonegap. First time once app is initialized, I am inserting all records in different tables and then use it on different pages.

On different pages i have opened database and getting data from the sqllite. But my issue is that sometimes on page it is not loading data from sqllite but as soon as i press app back button or app's back button it loads data.

Here is my code on different page on device ready. Will you please guide

```
    var db;
    $(document).ready(function(){       
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", getdata, false);       
    });
   function getdata()
   {
     window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "mayaa.db"});  
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK [This plugin](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin) doesnot support multi page architecture. I faced this issue couple of months back. Author told me to use a version which supports multipage architecture. I used [this verion and everything worked perfectly.](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin-2014.07)

Comment: I have left it and use html5 local storage instead.